# Upload and download information to an android application news application using some thing like Database on server

Tags: android, database

i have to build an android application that show news, each news dependent and the users can comment on each news dependently these news are frequently updated and the user also can upload new news how i should do this i think in a database found on the internet and my application deal with it from show to store so hope to get some ideas.

like this application on Google Play "Al Arabiya - العربية" completely

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question?

Comment: who i can start in coding this application i want some coding ideas to start

Comment: i want some ideas to start

Comment: i didn't try yet i need some codes to start with it